# When to use AttributeConverter?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, database-design

I would like to ask if there are some rules when to use AttributeConverter and when not. I mean when I should represent the field as one attribute in table and when I should create new table for that attribute.

Let me explain it on example. Let say I have some table and it has attribute color represented by RGB there are three possibilities how to represent it in DB.

1. In the original table create three attributes color-R, color-B, color-G and there store the values
2. Create new table color with attributes R, G, B
3. In the original table have one attribute color represented by string "123,255,255" representing the color and use AttributeConverter

Why I am asking is that I need to have some set of points with x,y coordinates which will be immutable (never changing) and I need to store it in database, I don't need to filter base on this values and I don't know how many (I know maximum will by 360) of them I will have. So I would like to know if it is good idea to save them as one string to database or I should create table "points" and make relationship between original table and "points" table (the first possibility from example above is not possible)?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-attributeconverter/) article will be helpful. See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert) section of hibernate documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but those links were about how to use AttributeConvertor and not when to use it. It didn't answer my main question.